# Dispersion of light by triangular prism

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

A glass prism is able to produce a spectrum when white light passes through it but a glass slab does not produce any spectrum.Explain the reason.
now in a glass slab light passes normally and i think so there is no dispersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you can see a spectrum in the prism is that light of different wavelength will go in different directions.

For a glass plate, any refraction caused to the light as it goes into the glass will be reverted when it goes out, causing all wavelength to travel in the same direction again.